# Developer Website Design

Tags: web-development, html, gui, css

I’m a developer and am willing to get into code but am terrible at UI. What are good resources for pre-made sites/templates or other resources for this?

Comment: what is your os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Dreamweaver is website creation software by Adobe Systems that's used to create websites with HTML, CSS and other Web programming languages. Dreamweaver also offers pre-made elements that can be dragged and dropped to assemble a fully functional website using a what-you-see-is-what-you-get interface.

Dreamweaver is integrated with other Adobe Creation Suite software including Photoshop and Illustrator; it supports a number of common and third party file extensions as well. Dreamweaver displays website projects in a live preview window where users see real-time changes take effect while editing HTML and CSS code. Dreamweaver's live preview window also allows users to place text, images, videos and script widgets into the website without writing a line of code.

Dreamweaver includes features that make creating mobile compatible websites faster, such as a fluid grid, Web fonts support and CSS3 transition support. The included templates serve as starting points for novice users who can plug in their own content and publish a website easily. They can also serve as objects of reference for more advanced users who wish to expand upon a design or learn new code elements.

Dreamweaver is available as a standalone Creative Cloud product or as part of the Creative Cloud Complete subscription as of May 2015. Adobe offers training courses and tutorials for all its software on its website.

Source: [Reference.com definition for Adobe Dreamweaver](https://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html)

Download Page: [Get Adobe Dreamweaver as part of Adobe Creative Cloud](https://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html)

*Note*: I think it's not a good idea to use Dreamweaver to edit UI directly because the UI doesn't show the exact view as it is in the browser. However you can preview your page in the program window or external browser. You didn't provide us your OS, Dreamweaver has Windows and Mac versions.

**Option 2:**

BlueGriffon® has a long list of famous ancestors and proudly inherits from all of them: Netscape®, Mozilla® Composer and Nvu. It is powered by Gecko, the same rendering engine you can find at the heart of Firefox®, and is filled with tons of powerful features...

http://bluegriffon.org/